# SQL Problem, Invalid ORDER BY Specification

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL query that I am having issues sorting. I am not sure if I need to input a bracket somewhere, could someone please help me out?

```
SELECT RESERVE.CHECKIN AS "Check-in",
       RESERVE.CHECKOUT AS "Check-out",
       RESERVE.RATE_REQ AS "Rate Code",
       RESERVE.GROUPCODE AS "Group",
       RESERVE.NIGHTS AS "Nights",
       HISTHD.USER2 AS "Booking Source",
       DAILYACT.TOTALROOMREVENUE AS "Daily Revenue"

FROM RESERVE
    INNER JOIN HISTHD
    ON RESERVE.CONFNUM = HISTHD.CONFNUM
    INNER JOIN DAILYACT
    ON RESERVE.CHECKIN = DAILYACT.AUDITDATE

WHERE (RESERVE.RESERVESTATUS = 'H') AND RESERVE.CHECKIN >= '{?Date\\RESERVE.CHECKIN}' AND NOT RESERVE.BEDTYPE IN ('COT1','PLAY')

UNION ALL

SELECT RESERVE.CHECKIN AS "Check-in",
       RESERVE.CHECKOUT AS "Check-out",
       RESERVE.RATE_REQ AS "Rate Code",
       RESERVE.GROUPCODE AS "Group",
       RESERVE.NIGHTS AS "Nights",
       FOLIOHD.USER2 AS "Booking Source",
       DAILYACT.TOTALROOMREVENUE AS "Daily Revenue"

FROM RESERVE
    INNER JOIN FOLIOHD
    ON RESERVE.CONFNUM = FOLIOHD.CONFNUM
    INNER JOIN DAILYACT
    ON RESERVE.CHECKIN = DAILYACT.AUDITDATE

WHERE (RESERVE.RESERVESTATUS = 'H') AND RESERVE.CHECKIN >= '{?Date\\RESERVE.CHECKIN}' AND NOT RESERVE.BEDTYPE IN ('COT1','PLAY')

ORDER BY RESERVE.CHECKIN
```

The exact error code is

> An error occurred executing statement. Invalid ORDER BY specification.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ORDER BY RESERVE.CHECKIN`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `RESERVATION` in your queried tables... Perhabs you meant `ORDER BY RESERVE.CHECKIN`?

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo! After correcting it though I am still having the same error. Fixed the typo on the original post.

Comment: Could you please add the DBMS you are using? There might be small differences among the systems, though we need to know which one you are using in order to check the syntax.